# R ggvis error "No data supplied to mark"

Tags: r, shiny, ggvis

I am struggling to incorporate a ggvis code into my shiny app. I get an error the description of which I cannot find on the web. The error is:

```
Error : No data supplied to mark.
```

Could please someone indicate what I am doing wrong? Thanks!

**ui.R:**

```
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("test"),
  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("INPUT","Upload your .xls:")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    ggvisOutput("PLOT")
  )
))
```

**server.R:**

```
library(ggvis)

shinyServer(function(input, output, session) {

  PLOTDF<-reactive({
    if (is.null(input$INPUT)==F) {

      library(gdata)
      tax<-read.xls(input$INPUT$datapath,check.names=F)

      plotdf<-data.frame(c(tax[1,1],tax[1,2]),c(tax[2,1],tax[2,2]))
      colnames(plotdf)<-c("a","b")

      plotdf

    }
  })

  reactive({
    plotdf_read<-PLOTDF()
    plotdf_read$data %>% ggvis(x=~a,y=~b) %>% layer_points()
    }) %>% bind_shiny("PLOT")

})
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with `gdata` but I have a few suspicions on the error.  It looks like your `PLOTDF` reactive function will return a dataframe `plotdf`.  I'm not sure why you have `plotdf_read$data` instead of `plotdf_read` in your plot statement.  `plotdf_read$data` is trying to get the "data" column from the dataframe -- it looks like the dataframe only has columns "a" and "b".  I think you mean to use `plotdf_read %>% ggvis...`.

Also here's a bit of a trick when it comes to passing in reactives into ggvis.  Right now this you are doing something similar to this:

```
reactive({
  PLOTDF() %>% ggvis(x=~a,y=~b) %>% layer_points()
  }) %>% bind_shiny("PLOT")
```

Basically, you are getting a data.frame in a reactive context and passing it into ggvis.  This will certainly work but I think there is a better way.

ggvis was designed to accept "bare reactives" -- we can pass into ggvis the reactive itself.  In the below code segment notice I pass `PLOTDF` into ggvis and NOT `PLOTDF()`:

```
PLOTDF %>% ggvis %>% ggvis(x=~a,y=~b) %>% layer_points()
%>% bind_shiny("PLOT")
```

What is the difference?  Well in the first example, every time your data.frame changes you will replot the entire ggvis.  In the second example, every time your data.frame changes only the data points in the ggvis will replot.

EDIT: improved grammar and explanations.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I have now tried what you suggested. If I go with `reactive({ PLOTDF() %>% ggvis(x=~a,y=~b) %>% layer_points() }) %>% bind_shiny("PLOT")`, it works. But if I try `PLOTDF %>% ggvis(x=~a,y=~b) %>% layer_points() %>% bind_shiny("PLOT")`, I get another error: `Error in if (!(length(col) == 1 || length(col) == nrow(data))) { : missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`. Do you have any clue what is wrong now?

Comment: I'm not quite sure.  Make sure when you do `PLOTDF %>% ggvis...` without the `()` that the ggvis statement is not wrapped inside a `reactive({ })`

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you posted `head(plotdf)` so that we can see what the DF inside the reactive looks like.

Comment: In this very simplified example `plotdf` looks something like that: `data.frame(c("A","B"),c(1,2))`. In the "real" code that I am writing it will be very similar: `data.frame(c("A","A","B","B","C","C"),c(1,2,3,4,5,6))`